# Convert String to Integer JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, scriptlet

I am a beginner using JSP. I want to display a list of incrementing integers using a maximum range of the users choice.

Entering: 6 should display the following:

- number 1
- number 2
- number 3
- number 4
- number 5
- number 6

input.jsp

```
<body>
<input type="number" name="numberMax" required>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</body>
```

jspResult.jsp

```
<body>
<% 
int numberMax = request.getParameter("numberMax");  // Cannot convert from String to int
%>
for (int i = 1; i <= numberMax; i++) 
{ %>
<ul>
<li><%= i %></li>
</ul>
<% } %>
</body>
```

How can I convert the input to an integer in order for the jsp scriptlet to print.

Comment: do you know about Integer.parseInt("6") ? This function can parse an String and return an int value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using this:

`<%int no = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numberMax"));%>`

Its working for me.

Comment: You may be interested in Integer.valueOf() - because it has small cache

Answer (score 4):

In case someone else lands here and is not allowed to use scripting elements for some reason.
You could use

`<fmt:parseNumber var="intValue" value="${integerAsString}" integerOnly="true"/>`

to set a new JSP variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSTL tags. The conversion from String to int then is done in the Expression Language.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
<body>
    <p>There are ${param.numberMax} numbers.</p>
    <ul>
    <c:forEach begin="1" end="${param.numberMax}" varStatus="no">
        <li><c:out value="number ${no.count}"/></li>
    </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</body>
```

The request parameters one gets as `param.numberMax` inside `${...}`.
The `varStatus` object contains properties like first or last time in loop and such.
Here the `<c:out >` tag is not needed, it can escape XML entities like turning a `&` into correct `&amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Integer.parseInt()' to convert string to integer.

```
<% 
 String paramNumMax = request.getParameter("numberMax");  // Cannot convert from String to int
 int numberMax = Integer.parseInt(paramNumMax.trim());
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest way to convert String into Integer:

```
String val="67";
int value=Integer.valueOf(val);
```