# JSP if statement - String to number

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am new to this so be gentle. I am working on a JSP page and would like implement an `if` statement.

`command.total` is set previously and I can't change its type.

```
<c:set var="number1" value="${5}"/>
<c:set var="number2" value="${0}"/>
<c:set var="number3" value="${command.total}"/>
<c:out value="${number1}" />
<c:out value="${command.total}" />

<c:choose>
<c:when test="${number1 < number2}">
${"number1 is less than number2"}
</c:when>
<c:when test="${number1 > number3}">
${"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${"cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"}
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

This always fails and I believe that the problem is that `command.total` is returned as a string.

I have tried to convert the string with the following:

```
<fmt:parseNumber value="command.total" var="test" integerOnly="TRUE" type="NUMBER"></fmt:parseNumber>
    <c:out value="${test}"></c:out>
```

Is it possible to convert this string to a number?

Comment: try: <fmt:parseNumber var = "command.total" type = "number" value = "${command.total}" />

Comment: Try to find out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219898/convert-string-to-integer-jsp)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of this please. Since you already have `c:set`, use some constant with the correct type (or use a scriptlet to set it if you want).